# Get to bottom of nav stack in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

How can I **get to the root bottom page** of a controller ?

It is like going to the first page and then removing all pages below, so that it is only the root page left without back buttons.

The same thing is usually done in a Tab-Based Application:
When there are some pages popped onto the root, and you press the tab you are on again, all pages above get removed.

Please help me how to do it and also what to import/inject.

Thanks a lot,
Cryptic Pug

Comment: Just use `this.navController.setRoot()`

Comment: Didn't work for me, somehow. However, I found a way and will post it later.